# astro-i18next Tfunction showing keys instead of translation

Tags: i18next, astrojs

I use `t()` function to translate text.
The function is acting like there are no locales in astros `/public` folder.

[My file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDw24.png)

My `translation.json` file for en:

```json
{
    "index": {
        "testHeader": "Test Header"
    }
}
```

Here is my index page code:

```js
---
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout.astro";
import { t, changeLanguage } from "i18next";

changeLanguage("en");
---

<Layout>
    <h1>{t("index.testHeader")}</h1>
</Layout>
```

My `astro-i18next.config.mts`:

```js
/** @type {import('astro-i18next').AstroI18nextConfig} */
export default {
    defaultLocale: "en",
    locales: ["en", "cs"],
};
```

My `astro.config.mjs`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import astroI18next from "astro-i18next";
import tailwind from '@astrojs/tailwind';
// https://astro.build/config
import react from "@astrojs/react";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
    integrations: [astroI18next(), react(), tailwind({
        config: './tailwind.config.cjs',
    })]
});
```

the `t()` function [shows the passed key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmbfO.png) instead of translation.
I runned `npx astro-i18next generate` which did nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using `npm update`.

For some reason my app's dependencies weren't updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue; I fixed it with a config change and a downgrade.
(since it's still in beta, gotta keep an eye on that)

NOTE: The current version of "astro-i18next" is "1.0.0-beta.17".

1. Add the following to your `astro-i18next.config.*`: `baseLanguage: "en"`
2. Downgrade your version to `1.0.0-beta.13`, between versions 10 to 17 only this one worked for me.
3. Good but not Necessary: add this to your `package.json` scripts: `"i18n": "npx astro-i18next generate"`
4. Run this command and should be successful: `pnpm i && pnpm run i18n && pnpm run build`

Considering this fix, I'm looking forward for similar issues to be resolved in stable release; However, for the time being this should get you going.

Comment: btw, I figured the `baseLanguage` missing error when I downgraded to v10; recommended approach for using beta libraries. Edge is trickier than it seems. ;))

Answer (score 0):

as drumsta commented in [this issue](https://github.com/yassinedoghri/astro-i18next/issues/103):

Adding the following configuration to the **astro-i18next.config**:

```
  i18nextServer: {
    backend: {
      loadPath: './public/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },
  },
```

this worked for me.